# display last working day of the next 12months in csv format using php

Tags: php, date, datetime, csv, command-line

i'm trying to solve a problem in php which is as follows:

aegis Media need to calculate when to pay their telesales staff. They are paid both a basic salary and a bonus, but not at the same time. The following business logic is in place:

● Staff get their basic monthly pay (salary), plus a bonus
● Basic pay is paid on the last working day of the month (Mon-Fri). So if the last day of January is the 31st, and this is a Saturday, the payment date is Friday the 30th. The same logic applies to Sunday.
● On the 12th of every month bonuses are paid for the previous month, unless that day is a weekend. In that case, they are paid the first Tuesday after the 12th

Requirements
The application should be CLI (command line) based and output a csv file.
The CSV file should contain the payment dates for the next 12 months. The CSV should contain a column for the month name, a column that contains the base payment date for that month, and a column that contains the bonus payment date.

heres what i've come up with

```
<?php

//Create an instance of now
$now = new DateTime( 'now', new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York' ) );

//sets the absolute last day of the month based off $now
$lastdateofthemonth = new DateTime( $now->format("Y-m-t"), new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York' ) ); 

$monthfromlastday = new DateTime( $now->format("Y-m-t"), new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York' ) ); 
$monthfromlastday->add(new DateInterval('P12M'));
//echo $monthfromlastday->format( 'd-m-Y' );


//testing last day of month
//echo $lastdateofthemonth->format( 'd-m-Y' );


if($lastdateofthemonth->format('l') == "Saturday") { 
    $lastdateofthemonth->modify( '-1 day' );
}
elseif($lastdateofthemonth->format('l') == "Sunday") { 
    $lastdateofthemonth->modify( '-2 day' );
    //echo $lastworkingday->format( 'l' );
}

//echo $lastdateofthemonth->format( 'd-m-Y' );

if($monthfromlastday->format('l') == "Saturday") { 
    $monthfromlastday->modify( '-1 day' );
}
elseif($monthfromlastday->format('l') == "Sunday") { 
    $monthfromlastday->modify( '-2 day' );
    //echo $lastworkingday->format( 'l' );
}

//echo $monthfromlastday->format( 'd-m-Y' );


//Define our interval (12months)
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');

//testing date interval setup
//echo $interval->format('%d days');

//Setup a DatePeriod instance to iterate between the start and end date by the interval
$period = new DatePeriod( $now, $interval, $monthfromlastday );

//Iterate over the DatePeriod instance
foreach( $period as $date ){
    //Make sure the day displayed is greater than or equal to todayy.
    //if( ){
    echo $date->format( 't-m-Y' ) . "<br />";

    //}
}



?>
```

i get the following result which is inaccurate:

```
31-08-2014
30-09-2014
31-10-2014
30-11-2014
31-12-2014
31-01-2015
28-02-2015
31-03-2015
30-04-2015
31-05-2015
30-06-2015
31-07-2015
31-08-2015
```

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong in my logic?
can anyone tell me how i can correctly list payment dates for the next 12 months in such a way that if the last
the last day of January is the 31st, and this is a Saturday, the payment date is Friday the 30th? 
The same logic applies to Sunday.

On the 12th of every month bonuses are paid for the previous month, unless that day is a weekend. In that case, they are paid the first Tuesday after the 12th, can anyone tell me how to model this with sample code based on the code i have above

Thank You.

Comment: I’d recommend using `strtotime` instead of doing all the work yourself … f.e. `strtotime('2014-07-01 last weekday')` will give you the last weekday of the previous month. And the second part is also quite easy with a simple check for whether the 12th is a weekend day, and if so again using strtotime with a relative natural language offset … but since this smells a lot like homework, I’ll leave figuring that out to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code initializes `$lastdateofthemonth` and `$monthfromlastday` as "today". e.g. Today is Friday, so your Saturday/Sunday tests fail - it'll test out as a Friday, and NOT be the last day of the month anyways.

You need to calculate the last-day-of-the-month FIRST, then check if it's a Saturday or Sunday.

e.g.

```
$now = newDateTime(); // create a "today" date, e.g. 2014-08-15
$first_of_month = $now->format('Y-m-01'); // 2014-08-01
$one_day = new DateTimeInterval('PT1D'); // 1 day interval
$last_day_of_previous_month = $first_of_month->sub($one_day); // 2014-07-31
$day_value = $last_day_of_previous_month->format('l');

if($day_value == 0) { // it's a Sunday
   $last_friday_of_month = $last_day_of_previous_month->sub($one_day);
   $last_friday_of_month = $last_friday_of_month->sub($one_day); // just reusing the inteval
} else if ($day_value == 7) { // it's a Saturday
   $last_friday_of_month = $last_day_of_previous_month->sub($one_day);
}
```